# Update gitignore changes in all branches

Tags: git, gitignore, atlassian-sourcetree

In my case I often meet such case:

1. I got develop branch which is a parent for all features branches
2. Importing some assets to feature branch with some files to be ignored I add it to
   .gitignore file
3. I merge that new feature with updated .gitignore file to develop branch.

Pretty common, but I still wish to keep ignored files locally and the problem is when I move to any other feature branch I can't merge develop into it because there are ignored files in project.

Is there any way to force update .gitignore changes in all the branches?

Comment: Do you use patterns for .gitignore or do you specify each asset separately? Can you give example?

Comment: For example I import "Spline" asset to Untiy, which has a directory of `Assets/Spline` in the project. Spline has a folder `Demo` with all sample scene resources which are not needed to be uploaded to repo, but it still may be useful for me to keep it locally and use sample scene.
In .gitignore I just add the line:
`Assets/Spline/Demo/`
As I mentioned the problem appears when I move to any other feature behind asset import date. Demo folder is still there and before merge the feature branch with "develop" branch I need to commit the changes (keeping Demo in the commit).

Answer (score 1):

Your `.gitignore` file is a *file* that you use and edit from your working tree.  Such files are not in *branches*, in Git: files are in *commits*.  (Any one given commit may—or may not—be contained in one or more branches, which is how branch names enter this picture.)  Once you realize this, and add in the fact that *no* commit, once made, can ever be changed—not even by Git itself<sup>1</sup>—you will find that there is no short-cut here:

- for each distinct branch-tip commit, you must *check out* that branch, update the `.gitignore`, add, and commit;
- if multiple branch names share the tip, you can then fast-forward-update each of the other branch names;
- repeat until all distinct branch-tip commits are updated.

While there's no short-cut for `.gitignore` files, `.gitignore` files are not the only way to exclude a file: there is also `.git/info/exclude` and your personal exclude file (e.g., `~/.gitignore` or `$XGD_CONFIG_HOME/git/ignore`).  Since this is not a working tree file, it does not get swapped around as you select other commits to work on.  But except for things like editor backups (e.g., "ignore all `*~` files in all my working trees because Emacs uses that as a backup name"), this tends to have limited applicability.

As [Sviatoslav Miller alluded to in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74168807/update-gitignore-changes-in-all-branches#comment130949958_74168807), if you can construct to-be-"ignored"<sup>2</sup> file names in some sort of regular repeated form, such as `*.local` or `ignoreme-*`, you can use the `.gitignore` pattern matching trick to good effect here.  Alternatively, consider using `git worktree` or multiple repositories, so that you do not have to keep swapping working trees from one branch name to another.

---

<sup>1</sup>Note that `git commit --amend` is a lie: it doesn't *change* a commit, it makes a *replacement* commit.  The original commit is not amended; instead, the original commit is kicked off the end of the branch, and the new commit is added to the end of the branch instead, so that it *looks like* the commit got amended.  But anyone using the original commit's hash ID through any *other* means still has the original commit.

<sup>2</sup>Note that listing a file in an exclusions file (`.gitignore` or `.git/info/exclude` for instance) does not actually *make* the file "ignored".  It simply avoids having `git status` *complain* about the file being untracked, and inhibits `git add` from *adding* the file to Git's index.  The presence of a copy of some file *in* Git's index is what defines whether that file is "tracked", and if a file is tracked, listing it in a `.gitignore` does not change that status.

Comment: Thanks for reply. 
I consider the option to use `git/info/exclude` but it will not fit in all the cases. Saying so, I can ignore some "demo" folder in imorted asset, but sometimes I also wish to keep that ignore over repo for all the other team members.
Jumping from branch to branch to update the .gitignore file seems not a big deal, but seems I can't understand how to do it properly, because I see newly added ignored folder in the changed files list (I use SourceTree, btw). This means, I can't pick updated .gitignore file until I commit the changes.